# Running Nodemon on IBM Power System i

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-midrange, ejs, nodemon

I am new to node development on power system i, was trying to get nodemon to work but errors out with following:

```
# nodemon.js

[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch ENOSYS
```

My application uses express, ejs and body-parser, works well outside of nodemon. First off, I couldn't get nodemon to be installed globally so I put that on my application node_modules directory and set the path, which is not what I usually do in other environments. How does `npm install -g` suppose to work on system i?
Any help on this greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

My environment is:

```
(node: v6.9.1)
(npm:3.10.8)
(OS:  V7R1)
Path: /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/OPS/Node6/bin:/QOpenSys/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/QOpenSys/usr/bin/X11:/usr/sbin:.:/usr/bin:/home/QSECOFR/projects/mytasklist/node_modules/nodemon/bin
LIBPath: /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/OPS/Node6/bin:/home/QSECOFR/projects/mytasklist/node_modules/nodemon/bin
```

Comment: Why "db2"? Why "bluemix"?

Comment: Related IBM threads

Comment: `ENOSYS` suggests that some functionality, presumably to watch for file changes, isn't present on that OS.

Comment: What could be that? Any information on that please? Dependency perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching, I think I found a solution.
I wasn't able to run directly Nodemon by typing

```
nodemon src/app.js
```

So on Node14 I found a workaround, adding a script line in package.json

```
 ... ,
  "main": "./src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "serve": "nodemon -L"
  },
```

Then run your application by typing
`npm run serve`

And voilà !

It seems to run in legacy mode.

Note : In node 10 this worked too (but not in node 14) even if my main file is src/app.js

```
"serve": "nodemon server.js"
```